# Dynamics AX 2009: Deleting discounts and added charges

Tags: dynamics-ax-2009, microsoft-dynamics, x++, axapta

Essentially, what I'm doing is this:

1. On insert, delete, or update on the SalesLine table, I'm checking the ProductCode of that line and determining whether or not a discount or miscellaneous charge applies
2. I have lookup tables for the charges and discounts
3. When any changes are made, I have to effectively remove the discounts/charges, because the newly modified SalesLine might not qualify for the charges/discounts

I have code that is doing what is described above -- but with the following side-effect:

- If I highlight several lines in the grid on the SalesTable Form, and click the toolbar's delete button, I get errors.
- The error(s) seem to be caused by my code deleting some of the items, and then the form is also trying to delete the lines after they've already been deleted by the code.

What would be the best way to erase the **added-by-code** discounts or charges when the parent line is deleted, that won't cause the form to blow up if a user selects those same lines for deletion?

Thanks in advance, this thing is *driving me crazy*!

EDIT: The specific error that I receive when the cached Form records try to get deleted is this:

**Cannot edit a record in Order lines (SalesLine).An update conflict occurred due to another user process deleting the record or changing one or more fields in the record.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious way to delete the `added-by-code` discounts or charges would be to add your table in the delete actions of the `salesLine` table with option `Cascade`. Also make a table relation on your table to the `SalesLine` talbe. In this way your records are deleted automatically. I would not do this if the discounts/charges are stored as sales lines though.

The error message make me guess, that you delete other sales lines, when deleting a sales line:

1. When deleting a "real" sales line you delete discount or charge lines.
2. When doing multi-line delete the #2 line has been deleted by the #1 line delete, but the form buffer has not been updated and the delete fails. This is effectively what the error messages tells you, a line has been updated since the record was read by the form.

Update for the delete problem:

1. Remove your code from the `SalesLine` delete methods.
2. Create a set of recId to be deleted later, populate in the `salesLine` datasource delete method.
3. Delete the lines later (maybe from the active method), if the set is not null.

Comment: The lookup table I'm using is really just a "does the product qualify for a miscellaneous charge or discount" lookup table. Lookups are done against the table, but the actual lines themselves are stored in the SalesLine table. Does this change the approach outlined in your first paragraph?

Comment: Depends, if you have a enum field to differentiate normal sales lines from discount, then you could do a self relation. Have you considered using MarkupTrans?

Comment: In this case, we have a field **MiscChargeRefId** that _if populated_ contains the parent record's **RecId**. If the field is _null_, then it is not a charge or discount line item. I'm not familiar enough with how MarkupTrans works to attempt it -- nor do I expect anyone to explain it in any great detail (unless it's relatively trivial). I'm still working on your suggestions, by the way. Thanks for the assistance thus far!

Comment: You could define a self relation, but I am not sure about the DeleteAction, a DeleteAction of cascade delete SalesLine on SalesLine does not sound right!